# Two octal numbers performing calculation using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create two octal numbers perform calculation in add and subtract using jQuery but if I try to calculate the two value it will only combine, do i need to convert parseInt var numberone and number two?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var numberone = $("#numberone").val();
        var operate = $("#operator").val();
        var numbertwo = $("#numbertwo").val();
        var answer;
        switch (operate) {
            case "addition":
                answer = numberone.toString(8) + numbertwo.toString(8);
                break;

            case "subtraction":
                answer = numberone.toString(8) - numbertwo.toString(8);
                break;
            case "multiplication":
                answer = numberone.toString(8) * numbertwo.toString(8);
                break;
            case "division":
                answer = numberone.toString(8) / numbertwo.toString(8);
                break;
            case "module":
                answer = numberone.toString(8) % numbertwo.toString(8);
                break;

            default:
                answer = "Error Try Again";
        }
        $("#answer").html("<h1>" + answer + "</h1>");
    });
});
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="numberone" type="number" name="" required="">
    <br>
    <select style="" id="operator">
        <option value="addition">+</option>
        <option value="subtraction">-</option>
        <option value="multiplication">*</option>
        <option value="division">/</option>
        <option value="module">%</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <input type="number" name="" id="numbertwo" required="">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
<br>
<span class="" id="answer"></span>
```

Comment: Could you indent your code correctly?

Comment: do not use .toString(), this will just concat the numbers. remove that and try it, if that doesn't work then use use .parseInt()

Comment: .parseInt(8)? sir

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt parseInt(value, base) e.g. parseInt(value, 8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace value.toString(8) with parseInt(value, 8) to get the base 8 version of that number:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var numberone = $("#numberone").val();
    var operate = $("#operator").val();
    var numbertwo = $("#numbertwo").val();
    var answer;
    switch (operate) {
      case "addition":
        answer = (parseInt(numberone, 8) + parseInt(numbertwo, 8)).toString(8);
        break;

      case "subtraction":
        answer = (parseInt(numberone, 8) - parseInt(numbertwo, 8)).toString(8);
        break;
      case "multiplication":
        answer = (parseInt(numberone, 8) * parseInt(numbertwo, 8)).toString(8);
        break;
      case "division":
        answer = (parseInt(numberone, 8) / parseInt(numbertwo, 8)).toString(8);
        break;
      case "module":
        answer = (parseInt(numberone, 8) % parseInt(numbertwo, 8)).toString(8);
        break;

      default:
        answer = "Error Try Again";
    }
    $("#answer").html("<h1>" + answer + "</h1>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <input id="numberone" type="number" name="" required="">
  <br>
  <select style="" id="operator">
    <option value="addition">+</option>
    <option value="subtraction">-</option>
    <option value="multiplication">*</option>
    <option value="division">/</option>
    <option value="module">%</option>
  </select>
  <br>

  <input type="number" name="" id="numbertwo" required="">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
<br>
<span class="" id="answer"></span>
```

However, there are still bugs in the code, such that it can output NaN etc.

Comment: if i put 7 + 7 it will get 14 instead of 16

Comment: if 07 + 07 because leading zero it will octal?

Comment: (parseInt(7, 8)+parseInt(7, 8)).toString(8)